# Python 3.5 | Split List and convert to csv

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv

I have two lists saved in two values. Those look like:

```
project_titles = ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']
project_loc = ['L1', 'L2', 'L3']
```

Actual I write the values with this Code into a csv:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerow(project_titles)
```

When I turn the csv to an excel I get:

- Cell A1 = T1
- Cell B1 = T2
- Cell C1 = T3

Thats fine, but I need the following result after the csv export:

- Cell A1 = T1; Cell B1 = L1
- Cell A2 = T2; Cell B2 = L2
- Cell A3 = T3; Cell B3 = L3

Do you have an idea?

Comment: keep a reference to `csv.writer(f)` and call `writerow` on that reference, so that you can call on it multiple times. The you can do something like `your_writer.writerow(project_titles)` then `your_writer.writerow(project_loc)`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) to aggregate elements from two or more lists, then write the resulting rows to the file with [`csvwriter.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows):

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(project_titles, project_loc))
```

Comment: the code works for two variables. Thank you for this. But I have five variable and need the first value of each variable in one row. I think the "pair" doesn't work. Do you have an other idea?

Comment: @Sebastian: you can apply the same idea to any number of lists as `zip()` can take any number of iterables. It may be easier to use `writerows()` instead of `writerow()` though.